# MongoDB validating send query, before executing it

Tags: mongodb

we are right now investigating MongoDB as the backend for some our software and encountered already a small issues.

When people send a query to mongo on top of our rest API, which wraps around Mongo inform of a spring repository, we would like to validate the input query against the syntax of mongo db.

Is there somewhere, where I could find the json schema, for all of Mongos possible query combinations?

kind regards

Comment: are you thinking about NoSql-injection or a kind of parse-before-fire?

Comment: i would just like to validate the provided query to make sure it conforms to the exspected format